# How to move & Re-Size DIV with smooth effect

Tags: jquery

i was trying to move div from bottom-right corner to center of the page and it was working but effect was not very soothing and was not very smooth. so i add this code to make it smooth in animate function `{ duration: 500, queue: false, easing: 'easeInCubic'}` but after that my code is not working. here i am giving my full code. just see and tell me what is wrong there for which my code is not running.

also tell me how could i move & resize my div in such a way as a result it should looks very smooth.

here is my code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#Button1").click(function () {
            $("form #UPSContainer").each(function () {
                $(this).remove();
            });

            $('form').append('<div id="UPSContainer" class="hidden" style="background:red;display:none;position:absolute"></div>');
            if ($("#UPSContainer").exists() == true) {
                $("#UPSContainer").css({ height: 0, width: 0, display: 'block' });

                var xleft = ($(window).width() - $("#UPSContainer").width());
                var xtop = ($(window).height() - $("#UPSContainer").height());

                $("#UPSContainer").css({ left: xleft, top: xtop, opacity: 0 });

                $("#UPSContainer").stop(true).animate({
                    'left': (($(window).width() - $("#UPSContainer").width()) / 2) + 'px',
                    'top': (($(window).height() - $("#UPSContainer").height()) / 2) + 'px',
                    'height': 100 + 'px',
                    'width': 100 + 'px',
                    'marginLeft': '-50px',
                    'marginTop': '-50px',
                    'opacity': '1'
                }, { duration: 500, queue: false, easing: 'easeInCubic'}, 
                function () {
                    //$("#feed_dialog").removeClass("BusyStyles").find('#acloginpod').fadeIn(2000);
                    //, opacity: 1 
                });

            }
            return false;
        });


        jQuery.fn.exists = function () { return this.length > 0; }
    });
```

js fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/p4e4psg4/2/

so i have two concern. one is why this line `{ duration: 500, queue: false, easing: 'easeInCubic'}` giving error ?

next very important is how could i have the animation with smooth effect? please help. thanks

### EDIT

see my script at js fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/tridip/pbyjkuxu/ the script is not running after adding this line `{ duration: 500, queue: false, easing: 'easeInCubic'}`

here i am giving another js fiddle link where a div is resizing but not positioning. just see the how smoothly a div is getting resizing http://jsfiddle.net/tridip/D5SUN/

i want the same smoothness in my div animation. please help. thanks

Comment: What's not "smooth" about the one on your jsFiddle?

Comment: If you're going to ask us to look at code that isn't working, it's better to show us the code that isn't working; since I can't find this line, `{ duration: 500, queue: false, easing: 'easeInCubic'}` in your demo, you may want to include that.

Comment: the easing `easeInCubic` does not exist in your version of the jQuery-UI. try your code with the latest version of jQuery and the jQuery-UI [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/u8180enw/)

Comment: `smooth` seems like a subjective issue when dealing with a 1/2 second animation.

Comment: please see my edit guys that my code is not working and also i gave another js fiddle link for what kind of smoothness i want for my animation. thanks

Comment: @Thomas as I said, please try your code with the newest version of jQuery and jQuery-UI. See the demo-link in my comment above. In addition, in your first fiddle, the jQuery-UI is missing

Comment: @empiric: i got your point but the div animation is not smooth. so i gave another js fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/tridip/D5SUN/. just see that how smooth that div resizing there. i want my div animation should be very smooth when appear from bottom-right corner to center. how can u help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In according to your fiddle I updated your code:

Try `{ duration: 800, easing: 'easeOutQuad'}` for a (I think so) 'smoother' animation.
I added a `opacity` to the div, as this was in the second example you gave us.

For checking the state of your animate via the `step`-function you can use:

```
step: function(now, tween){
    if(tween.prop === 'width'){
        if(now >= 50){
            console.log('Width reached 50%');
         }
    }
}
```

Through the `tween`-Object you can check the state of each attribute wich is animated in your function. (For the size you can e.g. check `width` and `height`); `now` referres to the actual value of the animated attribute.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/u8180enw/4/)

Anyway, in your provided example, the jQuery-UI is missing in the fiddle.
In fact, if a animation is smooth or not is very opinion-based and is very hard to answer.

Just play around a bit with the [easings](http://api.jqueryui.com/easings/) provided by the jQUery-UI core and some duration, until you are satisfied with the result.

I would recommend to use the latest versions of jQuery and the UI. Of course this is depending on your existing code and used Plugins.

Comment: @Thomas I'm glad I could help you, I modified my example a bit in according to your second example.

Comment: can i use step() function when increasing div size just like to determine when div size has been increased 50% ?